# Why is gradle not rebuilding when there is a change in one of its plugins?

Tags: plugins, build, gradle, task

I have created a plugin with a task that generates some java code, and that java code is then compiled in a later task. That all works fine.

But I see that when I change the task in the plugin, Gradle is rebuilding that plugin, but when it checks if the tasks should be run or not it simply says UP-TO-DATE. Doesn't it make more sense that when a plugin changes it will never be UP-TO-DATE?

I see the same behavior when there is a new version of a plugin that I use that is downloaded from Maven Central. I always need to do a manual clean to make sure everything is building as it should be.

Is this how it's intended? And is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: I think in Gradle, whether a task is UP-TO-DATE depends on whether the inputs and outputs differ from their snapshots in cache. A line of code change in plugin does not necessarily alter the inputs and outputs of the tasks it defines. How would Gradle know which line in the plugin affects which task?

Comment: Well, in my opinion, when a plugin is changed since the last build every task in that plugin should be building again. Because it can never be determined what task it will effect.

Comment: If your repository is small, you can afford rerun EVERY task even not created by the plugin. But in enterprise-level large repository, it could take 30 minute to just configure all modules, not to be executing the tasks. It is not wise to do so if your change is not affecting most tasks. I think Gradle team just leave the judgment to user. If you wish, you can run `gradle build --rerun-tasks` to force rerun.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. It doesn't matter how long it takes to build. If the tasks are not rerun, your build result is incorrect. So you need to do a clean anyway. And that probably takes longer, depending how tasks are divided over plugins. 
And the most import thing a any buildsystem is that you can expect correct results when you doing a build.

Comment: I agree it would be nice if Gradle can automatically identify all tasks from the plugin and their dependencies, rerun them once plugin is changed. But it is very difficult, if not impossible, to do so. If they ever made a choice, apparently they chose to not rerun any, rather than rerun every.

Comment: As @CrendKing said, whether a task is re-executed or not solely depends on its `inputs` and `outputs`. Can your alter the task generating Java code by adding something like `inputs.files configurations.pluginDeps.resolve()` to make the task depend on the libraries used to execute the plugin?